# Loading different versions of Jquery files

Tags: jquery

I have page on which I am using some third party controls. This assembly is loading jQuery version 1.3. But in my application master page I am using jQuery 1.8.3 due to which my page is not working properly. It is showing the below error message.

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Is there any way that I can solve this issue?

Thanks,

Praveen.

Comment: why can't you use version 1.3 on your master page?

Comment: Maybe this could help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Comment: There is jQuery noConflict() but better would be to use only the most recent jQuery version and upgrade older plugin

Comment: I am targeting the application to work in latest browsers. So I am planing to use latest JQuery version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to update the scripts to work with the newer version of jQuery. If that's not possible then you can use the jQuery.noConflict() method to create a safe reference to chosen version.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $1_3 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $1_8_1 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

You should be able to use it in the code:

```
$1_3.trim("   abc    ");   // "abc";
$1_8_1.trim("   abc    ");   // "abc";
```

It's not a perfect solution and I would recommend to use one version of jQuery only.